# Wildcard Targeting of Elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, class, wildcard

I am currently attempting to create a script that will add and remove classes from a number of elements on click.  The code works, but I would like to find a way to make it target a number of sequentially numbered sets of elements instead of just one set.  Here is the code I am currently using (**Updated**: 27 Nov 2013):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#tutorial-toc-step-01').click(function() {
    if ( jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked') && !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else if ( jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked') && jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
});
```

As you can see, the elements that are targeted are all numbered (at least the elements which vary from one set to the next).  I would like to target 1 through 9, but, currently, that would require me to replicate this script nine times, making only minor changes.  As I have a few different scripts like this on the page in question, I would much prefer to find a way to target each set without having to resort to multiple instances of (essentially) the same script.

**Update**: 27 Nov 2013: Here is a link to the HTML: http://zyniker13.com/html-pages/tutorial-template.html.  n.b., only the first set of elements will work, as I have not (yet) cloned and edited the jQuery from one for two through five.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: 27 Nov 2013: I have reworked the code to standardize the classes and ids involved.  This should make targeting easier, and added links to HTML.

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML?

Comment: You could use substring selectors to find a partial classname and do some logic from there [LINK](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @oGeez, yes, I am able to change the HTML.

Comment: @oGeez, I just updated the HTML, the classes and ids should be a bit easier to target, now.

Comment: @Zyniker Please post your HTML

Comment: @oGeez, I was in the process of doing so as you posted.  The post should be updated (with a link to the HTML) in a minute or so.

Comment: The answer to this question can be found in another thread (i.e., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292203/rework-jquery-scripts-to-utilize-wildcard-targeting-of-classes-ids) on a closely related topic.