# Rework jQuery Scripts to Utilize Wildcard Targeting of Classes/Ids

Tags: jquery, html, wildcard, addclass, removeclass

I currently have a (fairly sizable) JavaScript file which is used to animate some elements on a page.  There are four 'sets' of scripts used on the page, each set contains a number of scripts equal to the number of steps in the tutorial on the page.  What I would like to do is rework the scripts so that they will use wildcard targeting (if possible) instead of using the current setup (which is one script per function per step).  I will provide the first script from each of the sets:

**First Example**

```
/* ToC List Togglers */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#tutorial-toc-step-01').click(function() {
    if ( jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked') && !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else if ( jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else if ( !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
});
});
```

**Second Example**

```
/* Step Panel Togglers */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#tutorial-title-title-step-01').click(function() {
    if ( jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked') && !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else if ( jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else if ( !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
});
});
```

**Third Example**

```
/* Chevron Togglers */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#tutorial-title-chevron-step-01').click(function() {
    if ( !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-chevron-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    }
});
});
```

**Fourth Example**

```
/* Reset Togglers */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#tutorial-title-reset-step-01').click(function() {
    if ( jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').hasClass('glyphicon-check') && jQuery('#tutorial-step-01').hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').removeClass('glyphicon-check'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-01').addClass('glyphicon-unchecked');
    }
});
});
```

As you can likely guess, this current setup gets a bit cumbersome on pages that have more than a few steps (and almost unworkable on a page with dozens of steps).  If possible, I would like to rework these scripts so that they will work regardless of the number of steps.  As you can tell from the scripts, the steps and their elements are systematically and thoroughly id'ed and classed, which should help to some extent.  If necessary, the HTML can be edited to include fid's or other attributes/elements to make the jQuery more functional or easier to use.

For reference purposes, here is a page which is actually using these scripts: http://wordpress.omnifora.com/tutorials/create-a-button-to-change-the-font-on-your-site/.

Any help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you an example for the first block provided. There you have `#tutorial-toc-step-01`. So, give all similar elements a class, for example, `tutorial-toc-step-c` as well as save the number in additional field, for example, `data-stepnum='01'`. Then, the beginning of the code would like like that:

```
/* ToC List Togglers */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.tutorial-toc-step-c').click(function() {
    var stepnum = $(this).data('stepnum');
    if ( jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-'+stepnum).hasClass('glyphicon-unchecked') && !jQuery('#tutorial-body-step-'+stepnum).hasClass('in') ) {
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-'+stepnum).removeClass('glyphicon-unchecked'),
        jQuery('.tutorial-glyph-check-step-'+stepnum).addClass('glyphicon-check'),
        ...
```

I think, the idea is understandable. You'll have to rewrite each of those four blocks in a similar way.

By the way, was it intended that the first and the second code is absolutely the same except the clicked element `id`?

Comment: Yes, it was intended that those two should be the same except for the referenced id, I guess `||` is probably warranted.

Comment: Thankfully, your recommendation won't necessitate many changes to the HTML, as it already has fairly extensive sets of classes on the various elements for targeting purposes.  Really, I'll just need to rework the scripts and then add the `data-stepnum` attributes.

Comment: Okay, I got the entirety of the script file down to just under seventy lines (from an original four hundred).  That's a huge improvement, but I cannot seem to get the reset and chevron scripts functioning.  I've gone ahead and updated the page on which there used: http://wordpress.omnifora.com/tutorials/create-a-button-to-change-the-font-on-your-site/.  I'm not sure where the error is that's causing those two scripts not to work.

Comment: Looks like it may have just been some nesting issues.  Everything appears to be working now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Zyniker, I don't know how to use `||` in that case, but `jQuery('.tutorial-toc-step-c').add('.tutorial-title-title-step-c').click(function(){...})` should work - put same handler on both element sets.

Comment: `if ( ( jQuery('body').hasClass('page-id-21') || jQuery('body').hasClass('page-id-39') ) && jQuery('body').hasClass('parent-pageid-16') ) {` worked fine, but thanks for the .add() tip.